# No rule to make target 'C:/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_world300d.dll.a', needed by 'opencv.exe'. Stop

Tags: c, windows, opencv, cmake, clion

So I'm trying to build a simple opencv code but I keep getting this error and I don't seem to find any solution in the internet:

os: Windows 8.1

compiler GNU GCC 601

IDE: CLion

CMake 3.0 and mingw64

This is the code which I got from the opencv tutorial [page](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

And the CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(opencv)
set("OpenCV_DIR" "C:/opencv/build")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(opencv exemple.cpp)
target_link_libraries( opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Is this error I get. I checked the folder  C:/opencv/build/lib/ and it's empty

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build 
"C:\Users\Jorge Rodriguez\Downloads\opencv-tutorial-clion-master\opencv-
tutorial-clion-master\cmake-build-debug" --target all -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target opencv
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target                         
'C:/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_world300d.dll.a', needed by 'opencv.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/opencv.dir/exemple.cpp.obj
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/opencv.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencv.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

P.S: I'm new in programming so I would appreciate some specific instructions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Setting variable `OpenCV_DIR` to `C:/opencv/build` assumes that you have OpenCV **installed** into that directory. What content (files and directories) of the install directory is?

Comment: I have the same problem, in my.in my build directory is the files and folders from building openCV from library. I didn't find the file that error said was needed in my /lib but it wasn't empty.