# OpenCV makefile doesn't generate exectuable

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake, gnu-make

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to recreate the openCV tutorial with Cmake https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html

I downloaded the .exe for windows, built the sources with cmake via

```
cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

Then, I tried to use the make command in the project folder with the debug flag. I received this output:

```
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for i686-pc-msys
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'default_target'.
 File 'default_target' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'all'.
   File 'all' does not exist.
    Considering target file 'cmake_check_build_system'.
     File 'cmake_check_build_system' does not exist.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'cmake_check_build_system'.
    Must remake target 'cmake_check_build_system'.
Putting child 0x2004f248 (cmake_check_build_system) PID 22640 on the chain.
Live child 0x2004f248 (cmake_check_build_system) PID 22640
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I don't quite understand the output and googling for this didn't prove to be helpful. Since I don't have an executable file at the end (as mentioned in the tutorial), there seems to be some problem. What am I missing?

The CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/Users/XXX/opencv/opencv")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

CMake output:

```
cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles"
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenCV: C:/Users/XXX/opencv/opencv (found version "4.3.0")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/XXX/Documents/C++
```

make output (minGW-32)

```
mingw32-make.exe VERBOSE=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++ -BC:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++ --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++\CMakeFiles C:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/C++'
mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\DisplayImage.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/C++'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++ C:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++ C:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++ C:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++ C:\Users\XXX\Documents\C++\CMakeFiles\DisplayImage.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/C++'
mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\DisplayImage.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/C++'
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/Users/XXX/opencv_mingw/sources/build_mingw/lib/libopencv_dnn430.dll.a', needed by 'DisplayImage.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/C++'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/C++'
makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact command you ran to produce this output?

Comment: yes, I used "make -d" in the project folder

Comment: looks like there is no rule 'all'. Can you post your CMakeLists.txt ? And where you used cmake

Comment: I added the CMakeLists.txt. I used cmake in the root project folder containing my DisplayImage.cpp file and the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Please, show output of `cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles"` too.

Comment: I added the output for that too

Comment: If you generated MinGW Makefiles, the MinGW `make` executable should be `mingw32-make` or similar. Assuming you've setup MinGW correctly, can you run this command instead?

Comment: @squareskittles I uploaded the output of this command here: https://pastebin.com/SEEMzDhz

Comment: @squareskittles I fixed some path variables and got a shorter output I edited to my opening post

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378814/no-rule-to-make-target-c-opencv-build-lib-libopencv-world300d-dll-a-needed-b), but no posted solution yet...

Comment: I saw a comment there mentioned that his /lib folder was not empty. Mine is. According to the error message I should have files in that folder. Do you have an idea what might have gone wrong? I also tried CMake GUI with the same result